# How to validate the laravel input for spoofed input field name?

Tags: laravel, validation, validationrules

I have a input field as:

```
<input type="email" name="email" />
```

And it works fine with the laravel validation rules as:

```
 $rules = [
        'email' => 'email|required',
]
```

But if someone changes the HTML input field name using console something like:

```
 <input type="email" name="email[]" />
```

Laravel does not catch the validation and returns an error:
[image]

Is there any better way to handle such input manipulation in laravel?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see this as an issue. If someone is manipulating the input sent through your forms, a 500 response seems entirely appropriate. Why give them any hints as to what they did wrong attempting to mess with your site?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, but I just want to catch this and throw them a user-friendly message as something went wrong.

Comment: simply use try catch then throw on your user-friendly message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
$rules = [
    'email.*' => 'email|required',
  ]
```

this will validate each items in array

refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays

Answer (score 1):

the validator fails because the expected values are string but the submitted values are array. you can trap this validations by forcing the validator to only accept string and return an error if the values are array, try adding `string` to your validation rules.

you can also create a custom validation rule if you are validating an extra rules

you can play on different validation rules at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the problem here is with the validation field, not the validation rules actually. The validation rules work fine. But when someone manipulates the field name from string to array using chrome developer tool then the validation throws an error as attached above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_array()` function

for example

```
if(is_array($request->name))
    abort(500, "The \"name\" field can't be array");
```

or with short if statemant:

```
!isset($request->name) 
    ?: is_array($request->name) 
    ? abort(500, "The \"name\" field can't be array") 
    : $validation = $request->validate([
         'site' => 'required|string|email'
      ]);
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

change your validation rules

```
 $rules = [
        'email' => 'string|email|required',
     ]
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not actually the case. It's because of the field name, it's throwing an error, not because of the validation rule.